# Is it possible to define the Cantor power series tuple-function of infinite degree $f_\omega:\Bbb N^{<\omega}\to \Bbb N$?

Tags: limits, functions

> Is it possible to define the Cantor power series tuple-function of infinite degree $f_\omega:\Bbb N^{<\omega}\to \Bbb N$?

I suspect at the moment this is an open problem but I don't know that anybody has given it any thought. If it can't be defined yet, should we expect the solution to be unique - i.e. does the Fueter–Pólya conjecture imply a) existence and b) uniqueness of such a power series, and c) is there reason to expect the definition to be degenerate?

It is a [theorem of Rudolf Fueter and George Pólya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fueter%E2%80%93P%C3%B3lya_theorem) that the Cantor pairing function given by $\pi(x_1,x_2)=\frac12\left((x_1+x_2)^2+3x_1+x_2)\right)$ is the sole quadratic pairing function from $\pi:\Bbb N\times\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$, modulo exchanging $x_1$ for $x_2$.

The Fueter–Pólya conjecture is an open problem, claiming that the polynomial analogues of this function generated by induction of the same principle to $\Bbb N^n\to\Bbb N$ are the only such polynomial tuple functions.

These are given by $$f_n(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{k-1+\sum_{j=1}^{k}x_j}{k}$$

But I ask:  Suppose we can take $n\to\omega$.  Then I assume that being a polynomial of infinite degree, this would be a power series.  Is there reason to expect this power series tuple-function of infinite degree to be the only one, and is there hope to explicitly define it?

It seems relevant to mention that I am thinking that for every natural number this power series has finitely many nonzero terms.

Comment: I find closure without comment confusing... this isn't about maths apparently.

Comment: In case it is ambiguous, I'm asking whether we can determine a limit point of the sequence of polynomial tuple functions $\Bbb N^n\to\Bbb N$, which would be a power series tuple function.  But I also have a motivation to find a certain bijection $\Bbb N^{<\omega}\to\Bbb N$ whereby potentially unlimited many integers are require to map to some integer.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it is *unknown* if the result you seek holds for $\mathbb{N}^n$ (though it is *conjectured* to be true).  You want to know if this *unknown* result can be reasonably extended to an even less well described limit.  If we can't even say anything nice about the finite case, what makes you think that we will be able say anything reasonable about the *infinite* case?  More concretely, in what sense are you suggesting that the limit be taken?

Comment: @XanderHenderson No, I don't ask primarily whether an unknown conjecture can be extended. There is a *known* sequence of polynomials and I simply ask for its limit.  As for how that limit is calculated or defined... I leave open to reasonably justifiable interpretations.  Then as secondary matters to potentially add interest or background for the reader I mention the conjecture that the sequence is the sole sequence of polynomial tuple functions and invite informed opinion whether such a limit might also be unique.

Comment: It seems reasonable that some theorems might be provable for the infinite case more easily than the finite one. For example the terns of a sequence might belong to a set that's harder to work with than the set to which its limit belongs.

Comment: Or at least, it doesn't seem objectively UNreasonable. In principle it would involve finding something useful that can be said about the infinite case by virtue of its being infinite.